# Replace string pattern in Column Date with the correct format in R

Tags: r

Under my data frame, the Date column only is not in the standard format.  I want to change anything that say x1Q2013 to 2013-01-01  x2Q2013 to 2013-04-01 so forth until X1Q2023 to 2023-01-01

Thank you!

gsub can remove the front part, but how to add the back part and keep the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `zoo` you can convert quarter year to dates:

```r
library(zoo)
dates = c("x1Q2013", "x2Q2013")
as.Date(as.yearqtr(dates, format = "x%qQ%Y"))
#[1] "2013-01-01" "2013-04-01"
```